# Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 but getting the message "not a bootable disc"

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

This is on an Acer Aspire V5 (AMD 64-bit) with **Windows 8.1 pre-installed**. Have disabled secure boot and fast start-up; have tried with UEFI but it doesn't even try to boot from USB-HDD or USB-FDD in that mode, it just launches Windows; have tried in Legacy mode but getting the message "`not a bootable disc`": I have the .iso image on the USB drive - do I need to unzip the files for them to be recognised?

Comment: Is your ISO is good ? Check the ISO in virtual Machine !!

Comment: Open BIOS setting And Change Boot preference to USB..

Comment: have you just put the .iso file on the CD? That's not what you have to do -- you need to "burn" the iso onto the CD. There are many good guides online -- http://www.wikihow.com/Burn-ISO-Files-to-DVD

Comment: For putting the ISO on your USB stick, best use http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Boot preference is good; I will check the iso as I just downloaded it to the USB drive - I will check out unetbootin. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have the .iso image on the USB drive - do I need to unzip the files for them to be recognised?

What method did you use to write the ISO to USB? (I'm just guessing here, but if you simply copied the ISO file to the USB, it won't work.)

Please try to write it using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on Windows.

1. Download and run Unetbootin
2. In the Diskimage section, select your ISO file and your USB drive.
3. Click on **OK** and wait for it to finish.

Comment: I used UNetBootin and was able to proceed with the installation, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check ISO File is Good (Check in virtual Machine) If your ISO is Running Perfect in Virtual Machine When Download **LILI LINUX**
[From Here](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download)

After installing LILI LINUX insert your USB Drive and open **LILI LINUX** then
[image]